# Printing one iWork Pages-page, twice, on one physical paper?

Tags: pages, printing

I wrote a short text that would be suitable to print on A5 but I only have A4 in my printer. I need ten physical copies of this text, that is five A4 with it printed twice.

Is it possible to print the same page **twice** on **one** physical paper? And then repeat that five times?

Please note that I **don't want/need** to **print on both sides** of a physical paper.

I found some instructions to setup facing pages here https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/pages/tan026e4c95a/mac but that is not what I want (at least it didn't seem to work the way I wanted/expected).

My current workaround is to create two pages in Pages with identical content and then print two Pages pages on one physical paper (not printing double sided) but this is annoying when I want to update the content and print it again.

Comment: See also [How do I print a single page document to multiple copies, double sided?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/374341/how-do-i-print-a-single-page-document-to-multiple-copies-double-sided)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that involves an additional saved file and use of the Preview application in addition to the Pages application, but achieves the goal of printing multiple pages twice without duplicating the content within the Pages document.

Unlike Pages, Preview has a "Copies per page" option in its print menu which will print the same document multiple times on the same page.  Using this option, you can save the Pages file as a PDF, open that PDF file in Preview, and then use the "Copies per page" option to print the document multiple times.

Note that it is possible to open a Pages file directly in Preview.  However, the formatting doesn't always exactly match the Pages formatting.  Therefore, depending on the level of document fidelity needed, printing to PDF should be used to ensure correct formatting.

### Step-by-step directions

First, save the document as a PDF using the "Save as PDF" option in the print dialog under the "PDF" menu in the bottom-left corner of the dialog.

[image: Pages print dialog showing "Save as PDF" option]

Next, open the PDF in Preview.  Select "2" for the "Copies per page" option.  Set the number of copies to the desired amount (5 in your case).  Set any other desired print options, then click the "Print" button.

[image: Preview print dialog showing "Copies per page" option]

This will print two pages on each physical sheet, as desired.

Answer (score -1):

While I don't use Pages.app the macOS print dialog box is pretty standard and that option is to be found in most apps.

In Safari (below) when you go to print, you get this when you select "Layout" from the pop-up menu halfway down the dialog:

[image: Print Layout]

You merely need to select 2 pages per sheet and will print a single page "two up" as they say. Note that if you have a two (or 3 or 4...) page document it will print page 1 and 2 on the first sheet of paper.

Comment: Doesn't work. The resulting paper contains just one copy of the page content. That is why I have to create two pages in Pages that are identical.

Comment: In Safart is even more cumbersome, then you have to generate a PDF of the content, duplicate that PDF and make a new PDF with two identical pages. Then you can use the setting you describe above.

Comment: What if you specify 2 copies and 2 pages per sheet? (Bonus: for multipage documents, try 2 copies, 2 pages per sheet, and uncheck “Collate”.)

Comment: You'd think this ought to work, 10 copies 2-per-sheet, but it doesn't. The second page ie the right side of the sheet, comes up empty. This is rather counter-intuitive. If you tell it to print 2 or more pages this way, even using double-sided, it will physically print 2 sheets, each with just the one copy:\ The only option I can see is to rotate the paper manually after 5 copies printed this way & run the job again. In the print trade, this is known as 'work & twist'.

Comment: Pages per Sheet puts pages 1 and 2 on the same sheet: it doesn't duplicate page 1.